# UPDATE a table to erase a long string of html

Tags: html, mysql, wordpress

I'm fixing a friends wordpress site, and I've discovered that his previous malware infection added a long string of html to the end of hundreds of posts.  This is the html:

```
<div style="position:absolute;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0.001;z-index:10;">
<a href="http://...">...</a></div>
```

I can write an UPDATE SET REPLACE for small strings.  But I can't figure out how it's possible to find this exact string, given all the html and quotation marks.  Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my updated query:

```
UPDATE posts
SET post = SUBSTRING(post, 1, INSTR(post, '<div style="%position:absolute;') - 1)
WHERE post LIKE '%<div style="\%position:absolute;%'
```

It replaces each post which contains the substring `<div style="\%position:absolute;` with the substring of that post beginning at the first character and ending with the last character *before* the start of the garbage added at the end.

This should work under the assumption that the garbage html always appears at the end, and that `<div style="\%position:absolute;` only appears as the garbage text and is never part of an actual post.

Comment: That's a neat solution, but unfortunately, it won't work in my case because the string length that I need to delete varies a little.  The string does, however, always begin the same.  So, playing off of your answer, is it possible to count the number of characters before the occurrence of a specific string?  Because that would allow for finding the length of valid content, and we could trim to that length.

Comment: Thank you!  That saved me an inordinate amount of manual editing.